# Put the http.Handler in martini

Tags: go, martini

How do I integrate just like `http.FileServer` with martini? 
`   package main

```
import (
    "github.com/go-martini/martini"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    m := martini.Classic()
    //http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))) //It doesn't work!
    m.Run()
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the FileServer isn't used directly in Martini: see [issues/20](https://github.com/go-martini/martini/issues/20):

> Unfortunately The fileserver middleware throws a 404 if there is no match, which means we will need to roll our own

Hence [PR 26](https://github.com/go-martini/martini/pull/26) and [commit a945713](https://github.com/go-martini/martini/commit/a945713cdd5c8f7413ef6d07f897e2c9faff8531) in [`static.go`](https://github.com/go-martini/martini/blob/a945713cdd5c8f7413ef6d07f897e2c9faff8531/static.go) that you can see in [`static_test.go`](https://github.com/go-martini/martini/blob/7d32ea3fa6590565c928b90a48178b60b96df98f/static_test.go)

```
m := New()
r := NewRouter()
m.Use(Static(currentRoot))
m.Action(r.Handle)
```